# Installing python module to another directory

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, installation

I have 2 installations of Python 2.7 installed on my PC. One is in `C:\Python27`, and the other is in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Python_2_7`. I personally use the second one. The registry contains the path to the second installation directory as well, in the key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Python\PythonCore\2.7\InstallPath`. When I install Python packages, I have to install from source to have it install into the correct directory. When I use executable installers, it always finds the first Python interpreter. I was not able to find out how to correct this.

How can I change the default installation directory for EXE packages? After I run any .exe, I am not able to change the directory there. With MSI it is possible using `msiexec /i <package>.msi TARGETDIR="C:\Program Files (x86)\Python_2_7\"`. With source installations, I can just use the correct `python.exe`.

Comment: It's probably installed for the current user, i.e. in the registry key `HKCU\Software\Python`.

Comment: Nope, there is Python, but nothing about path there

Comment: When you say that the registry contains the path "to it as well", are you talking about the installation in `C:\Python27` or the one in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Python_2_7`?

Comment: I mean the last one, yes, C:\Program Files (x86)\Python_2_7

Comment: Also check `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Python`.

Comment: Yes, its there, corrected now, thank you! Not really an obvious thing to find heh

Comment: Administratively speaking, it's important to to be aware of how WOW64 is implemented to allow seamlessly running 32-bit applications on 64-bit Windows. See [Registry Keys Affected by WOW64](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384253).